# Define permanent static ip at fedora server 36 without nmcli command

Tags: networking, fedora, ip, networkmanager, nmcli

Working with VirtualBox 6.1.38 and `Fedora` **Server** 36 as the guest, about to define a static ip address, I am reading many tutorials about how to do this, the `nmcli` command is involved.

Something cumbersome is that the `UUID` shown through the `sudo nmcli connection show` command must be used later for the following commands:

```
sudo nmcli connection modify <UUID> IPv4.address 192.168.1.X/24
sudo nmcli connection modify <UUID> IPv4.gateway 192.168.1.1
sudo nmcli connection modify <UUID> IPv4.dns <something>
sudo nmcli connection modify <UUID> IPv4.method manual
sudo nmcli connection down <UUID>
sudo nmcli connection down <UUID>
```

Because it is a server environment, does not exist clipboard support, therefore is not possible do a copy/paste of the UUID value.

As ubuntu has the `/etc/netplan/01-netcfg.yaml` file to edit and configure the static ip address, is there something similar for `Fedora`?

If does not exist the requested file, what could be the best approach to re-use quickly that UUID value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did realize the following, the `sudo nmcli connection show` command shows the `NAME` header too, it such as `enp0s3`, therefore the following commands

```
sudo nmcli connection modify <UUID> IPv4.address 192.168.1.X/24
sudo nmcli connection modify <UUID> IPv4.gateway 192.168.1.1
sudo nmcli connection modify <UUID> IPv4.dns <something>
sudo nmcli connection modify <UUID> IPv4.method manual
sudo nmcli connection down <UUID>
sudo nmcli connection down <UUID>
```

can be replaced by

```
sudo nmcli connection modify <NAME> IPv4.address 192.168.1.X/24
sudo nmcli connection modify <NAME> IPv4.gateway 192.168.1.1
sudo nmcli connection modify <NAME> IPv4.dns <something>
sudo nmcli connection modify <NAME> IPv4.method manual
sudo nmcli connection down <NAME>
sudo nmcli connection down <NAME>
```

Therefore now - for a **server** environment - is easier use `NAME` as **enp0s3** just once and then use the command history (up arrow key) and change quickly the `IPv4.XXX` part with the respective new value

Answer (score 1):

- there is bash completion which works really well.
- the multiple `nmcli connection modify` commands can be all combined in one modify call.
- the profiles are of course stored in a file. You can see the filename in `nmcli -f all connection`. Edit the file, and issue a `nmcli connection reload` afterwards. Check the result with `nmcli connection show "$UUID"`. Read `man nm-settings` and `man nm-settings-keyfile` for documentation about the file format.
- this is shell. You can do various kinds of things for convenience, including using a variable or writing a shell function/script.

```
u=...
nmcli c m $u $options
```